# Web Page front end with C computation in the Back end

Tags: php, c, user-interface

Hi I have a couple of C programs which are accept a certain input and make some complex computations to calculate the output.

Now my aim is to make the C programs as a background process which is called by web-UI by supplying the input and retrieving the output and displaying it in the web-UI.

How may I bind my C programs with a Web oriented language like php for instance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke a system call with [back-tick operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) such as:

```
$ouput = `yourprogram arg1 arg2`;
```

Please note, you must must must sanitize your input if you are expecting to pass user data into this command.

**However**, since you've stated you wish to run this in the background, I suggest checking out a message queueing system such as [Gearman](http://gearman.org/), which has C libraries(for both workers and clients) which would help in hooking into your C application. Gearman also has plenty of libraries for web languages such as PHP.  Gearman supports both synchronous and asynchronous(aka background) tasks.

Comment: Getting the output to the php variable will not be a problem. But passing the php variable to the C program as input might cause problems since php is Weak type language.. How do we overcome this issue?